# Div width occasionally not rendering (safari only)

Tags: html, macos, safari, redraw

I'm calculating a width of a div and setting it using javascript. But occasionally on safari on the mac it will not render the size. Even though I clearly have the width style on the element and no important statements overriding it the calculated width remains 0. It's really strange and only happens occasionally. See screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Re1tg.jpg

Has anyone had this problem before or could please offer any suggestions?

Thanks

Edit js code

```
setResizeFlag = function(){
   resizeComplete = true; 
   clearInterval(periodicalResize);

   windowSize = window.getSize();
   siteWidth = header.getSize().x;
   content.setStyle('width',siteWidth + 'px');
}

window.addEvent('resize', function(){
   resizeComplete = false;
   if(periodicalResize) clearInterval(periodicalResize);
   periodicalResize = setResizeFlag.periodical(500);
});
```

Comment: Please show us your js code

Comment: @Gwenc37 

Hi

I'll add it to my original question

Thanks

Comment: @Gwnec37  Actually mate i think i might have found out what it is now.....Typically i've spent hours looking before i made a post then as soon as i did i've come across the problem (hopefully).  

I think it is due to the content div having css transitions on the width.  So far since i've taken that off i've not been able to replicate the problem.